# Using react-router v6 I need a navbar to permanently be there, but can't display both <App/> and <Home/> on my index page, how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am rebuilding my personal site with React and have decided on the latest version of react-router-dom, I am building my `App` component to contain the navbar and then underneath the content I want to display, such as `Home` or `Projects`. This works fine on my `/projects` route but I cannot seem to work out how to render both `App` and `Home` on the index route. Is there a way? Here is what I have so far:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
// N.B. Routes replaces Switch as of V6

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        // Using <App/> here keeps the navbar but doesn't display the homepage content
        <Route path="/" element={<App/>}>
        // But using <Home/> loses the navbar
        // Should I have my Navbar component in here somewhere or within the App?
          <Route path="projects" element={<Projects/>}/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

function App() {
  // Help?
}

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <header> // Very crude example as I'm self-answering, in production I'll rename the component to Header
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/projects">Projects</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
}

function Home() {
  return <h1>Home</h1>
}

function Projects() {
  return <h1>Projects</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 21):

If you followed the tutorial for React-Router 6 and used the `createBrowserRouter` function, and don't want to change to using `<BrowserRouter>`, you can do the following conversion:

### Start

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/", 
        element: <Root/>
    },
    {
        path: "/somePath", 
        element: <SomePath/>
    }
])

root.render(
    <div>
        <NavBar/>
        <RouterProvider router={router}/>
    </div>
)
```

Navbar shows error `useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component`

### Conversion

Restructure your `createBrowserRouter` object so that you have a path "/" with your Navbar component and an `<Outlet/>`.

```js
import {Outlet} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/", 
        element: <NavbarWrapper/>
        children:[
             {
                 path: "/", // yes, again
                 element: <Root/>
             },
             {
                 path: "/somePath",
                 element: <SomePath/>
             },
        ]
    }
])

const function NavbarWrapper(){
    return (
    <div>
        <Navbar/>
        <Outlet/>
    </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 8):

The app can just unconditionally render the `Navbar`, and move the `Routes` component and routing to `App`. The index file renders `App` into the `BrowserRouter`.

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}>
        <Route path="projects" element={<Projects/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thanks Drew :) that is in fact a much neater solution than my own, and one that I wish had worked for me when trying it - I must have been doing something wrong! I have got it working my way below so I haven't dared trying to change it yet, but I suppose that's what Git is for!

Comment: @Gavin Oh, I hadn't even noticed it was a self-answer. Sure, using a layout component rendering an `Outlet` is the other way to accomplish this. I didn't go that route since you said you wanted to render the `Navbar` on permanently. The layout wrapper components are useful if you want to group routes into different layouts (i.e. with different UI/UX layouts, navbars, etc...).

Comment: Thought you'd like to know that I've got it working this way now! :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here is what your `App` component will look like:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <main> // You don't *have* to wrap the Outlet in a main tag, but I am doing, to save having to remember to do it in each component
        <Outlet/>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

So that now your `App` always displays the `Navbar` and the outlet will display whichever page the route tells it to.

*Okay that's great, but it still means rendering `App` when I want to be rendering `Home` and still keeping that navbar, does this really fix that?*

Well, not on its own. First add that Outlet component to your import from `react-router-dom`, otherwise we're getting nowhere!

Now adjust your routing like so:

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Outlet, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App/>}>
          <Route index element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path="projects" element={<Projects/>}/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

See how that `Route` tag with the `Home` component has the `index` tag on it? That's it, that's the solution! Now your App renders as it should, navbar included, and its `Outlet` renders the `Home` element on the index route.